# How to Create a Azure managed Disk using snapshot from Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

How do I create an Azure managed Disk using snapshot from PowerShell?

I'm able to create managed disk using snapshot from Azure portal, But how to do the same using PowerShell?

[image: Azure Portal]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below script to create snapshot of Managed Disk using  in the region which you need. In the below script you can enter details of Subscription ID , Resource Group Name and other components as per needed and you should be able to create the snapshot for same

```
#Provide the subscription Id
$subscriptionId = 'yourSubscriptionId'

#Provide the name of your resource group
$resourceGroupName ='yourResourceGroupName'

#Provide the name of the snapshot that will be used to create Managed Disks
$snapshotName = 'yourSnapshotName'

#Provide the name of the Managed Disk
$diskName = 'yourManagedDiskName'

#Provide the size of the disks in GB. It should be greater than the VHD file size.
$diskSize = '128'

#Provide the storage type for Managed Disk. PremiumLRS or StandardLRS.
$storageType = 'Premium_LRS'

#Provide the Azure region (e.g. westus) where Managed Disks will be located.
#This location should be same as the snapshot location
#Get all the Azure location using command below:
#Get-AzLocation
$location = 'westus'

#Set the context to the subscription Id where Managed Disk will be created
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName 

$diskConfig = New-AzDiskConfig -SkuName $storageType -Location $location -CreateOption Copy -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -DiskSizeGB $diskSize
 
New-AzDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName
```

Source [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-samples/blob/master/virtual-machine/create-managed-disk-from-snapshot/create-managed-disk-from-snapshot.ps1).

You can make use of the powershell commands as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/snapshot-copy-managed-disk?tabs=powershell) as well:

1)Set the required parameters. Update the values to reflect your environment.

```
$resourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup' 
$location = 'eastus' 
$vmName = 'myVM'
$snapshotName = 'mySnapshot'
```

2)Use the Get-AzVM cmdlet to get the VM containing the VHD you want to copy.

```
$vm = Get-AzVM `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $vmName
```

3)Create the snapshot configuration

```
$snapshot =  New-AzSnapshotConfig `
    -SourceUri $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id `
    -Location $location `
    -CreateOption copy
```

4)Take the snapshot:

```
New-AzSnapshot `
    -Snapshot $snapshot `
    -SnapshotName $snapshotName `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).